# Would Microsoft Graph paging over Users collection using @odata:nextLink work if access token expires in between?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a use case where I need to iterate over the Users collection using the @odata:nextLink (not using GraphClient, I am using HttpClient). The Users collection can be really large. The question that I have is, during the iteration over the Users collection, if there is a failure due to access token expiry, would the @odata:nextLink work seamlessly with a new access token. Or in other words, is the continuation token tied to the access token.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `@data.nextLink` will work with a new access token.

In the `@odata:nextLink` there is a `$skipToken` parameter which contains an opaque token that references the next page of results.

The `$skipToken` usually identifies a starting point in the collection of entities identified by the URI containing the `$skiptoken` parameter.

There is no connection between the token in the `@data.nextLink` and the access token.

[skipToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skiptoken-parameter)